# Looking for files in one class and outputing/progressbar in the other

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

First problem I'm having is reaching my list's size, in the MainWindow when I'm calling my class' getResult().size() it's zero even though it's increasing finely in the filesearch class(if you print it out during search).

Second is I need help how to make two swingworkers communicate between two classes. In one class it's looking for files, and in MainWindow it's moving progress bar.

I've found that I need to do something with SwingPropertyChangeSupport but I wasn't able to implement it.

I tried creating two swingworkers in each class, one for outputing in MainWindow and the other for search(extending FileSearch class)

And since I'm looking for files recursively I'm not sure if this is the right way to do so

```
  if (temp.isDirectory()) {
        new FileSearch(getFileNameToSearch(),temp).execute();
}
```

this thing ^

```
public class FileSearch extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

private String fileNameToSearch;
private List<String> result;
private File file;

public FileSearch(String fileNameToSearch, File file) {
    this.fileNameToSearch = fileNameToSearch;
    this.file = file;
    result = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getFileNameToSearch() {
    return fileNameToSearch;
}


public List<String> getResult() {
    return result;
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());

        if (file.canRead()) {
            try{
                for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                        new FileSearch(getFileNameToSearch(),temp).execute();
                    } else {
                        String temp2 = temp.getName().toLowerCase();
                        String trimmedName = temp.getName().toLowerCase();
                        try{
                            trimmedName = temp2.substring(0, temp2.lastIndexOf("."));
                        }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                        }
                        if (getFileNameToSearch().equals(trimmedName)) {
                            result.add(temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                            System.out.println(result.size());

                        }else{
                            System.out.println(getFileNameToSearch() + "!= " + trimmedName);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){

            }


        } else {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
        }
    }
    return result.size();
}
```

And MainWindow

```
    public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
    initComponents();
    fileChooser1.setApproveButtonText("Select");
    fileChooser1.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    directoriesTextArea.setEditable(false);

}

private void startButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    directoriesTextArea.setText("");

    SwingWorker<Void, String> worker =  new SwingWorker<>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            File file = new File(absolutePathTextField.getText());
            FileSearch filesearch = new FileSearch(fileNameTextField.getText(), file);

            filesearch.execute();

            int count = filesearch.getResult().size();

            if(count == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "There are no such files");
                System.out.println(count);
            }else{
                for(String matched : filesearch.getResult()){
                    publish(matched);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for(String matched : chunks){
                directoriesTextArea.append(matched + "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            directoriesTextArea.append("\nDone!");

        }
    };

    worker.execute();


}
```

=================EDITED VERSION=================

```
private void startButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    directoriesTextArea.setText("");
    progressBarCounter = 0;
    progressBar1.setValue(0);


    SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            File file = new File(absolutePathTextField.getText());
            FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch(fileNameTextField.getText(), file);

            folderCount(file);
            searchFiles(file);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for(String file : chunks){
                directoriesTextArea.append(file + "\n");
            }
        }
        protected void folderCount(File file){
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                if (file.canRead()) {
                    try {
                        for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
                            if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                                folderCount(temp);
                                folderCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }
                }
            }
            progressBar1.setMinimum(0);
            progressBar1.setMaximum(folderCount);
        }


        protected void searchFiles(File file) {
        progressBarCounter++;
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + file.getAbsoluteFile());

                if (file.canRead()) {
                    try {
                        for (File temp : file.listFiles()) {
                            progressBar1.setValue(progressBarCounter);
                            if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                                searchFiles(temp);
                            } else {
                                String temp2 = temp.getName().toLowerCase();
                                String trimmedName = temp.getName().toLowerCase();
                                try {
                                    trimmedName = temp2.substring(0, temp2.lastIndexOf("."));
                                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                                }
                                if (fileNameTextField.getText().toLowerCase().equals(trimmedName)) {
                                    System.out.println(fileNameTextField.getText() + " == " + trimmedName);
                                    publish(temp.getAbsolutePath());

                                } else {
                                    System.out.println(fileNameTextField.getText() + "!= " + trimmedName);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                    }


                } else {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    worker.execute();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the progress / process combination. In the background thread you need to regularly call the process method, to state how far along the background process is. Subsequently, the progress method is called for you (within the EDT thread) and there you can update the progress bar.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: But how am I going to get those values for progress bar  from filesearch progress/process combination in my EDT ?

Comment: This is what swingworker is handling for you. Just call the progress method, and swingworker will call process for you in the EDT.

Comment: Just making this clear, am I supposed to create new SwingWorker in MainWindow class for outputing matched files in text area or not ?

Comment: You have two thing setup wrong: 1) you use SwingWorker twice, once in the filesearcher, one in the main window. Only use it in the main window. 2) Move the file search logic (for now) to the doInBackground in the main window and call the progress method. After it is working you can refactor.

Comment: Okay so everything's working while it's in mainwindow, so placing search in other class now. As much as I understand I need to make FileSearch Runnable/Thread and place that search in run method, right? And then with property change listeners pass information about found files to swingworker's doInBackground method ? Correct me here please

Comment: Even though I do not like that approach, yes. You provide the SwingWorker.getPropertyChangeSupport() to the FileSearch class and then call firePropertyChange("progress",...) from within that. You do not need to do any thread or runnable handling yourself, calling SwingWorker.execute will execute doInBackground on a worker thread.

Comment: So in my EDT I'm outputing information passed from FileSearch class, but it's made of two types of info - found files, and progress bar update, so I will need to firepropertychange twice? Once when found file and once when to update progress bar? Am I supposed to do both fires with "progress" value ?

P.S. Maybe it's better to use swingPropertyChangeSupport than regular propertyChangeSupport?

Comment: No, you can only provide an integer value representing the progress. If you want to communicate more data, maybe should not use SwingWorker. Which is not difficult; it is a matter of starting something on a worker thread and when you normally would call progress() you use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) to do the UI update.

Comment: Okayy it seems everything's okay, thank you very much for your patience! :D